# How to use DDD in practice?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I have some doubts about how to use DDD approach in real project.Roughly speaking, in my app I have two types of operations: simple CRUD operation, which is quite simple, just create or update records in DB and do not require a lot of business logic and some operation which require it.
For both types of operation I use services to avoid some kind of "asymmetry", but for CRUD operations it looks like overhead, because I just wrap save() method in service method and it is does not add any logic.

So what is the best approach according to your experience make simple (CRUD) operation in controllers or put it in services or may be you have some other ideas?

Comment: Have you identified your bounded context(s), aggregates? What do you mean when you mention DDD?

Comment: For the CRUD architecture you should keep things as simple as possible, without many unnecessary layers. For the other more complex you could apply DDD: identify bounded contexts, aggregates, entities, value objects. Depending on the complexity and business requirements (scalability, maintainability, number of users etc) you choose a high level architecture (i.e. Onion Architecture/Ports and Adapters) and a low level architecture  (i.e. CQRS)

Comment: DDD is an approach for handling complex domains. In your case it does not sound like you need it. Check out Vaughn Vernon's score card: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1944876&seqNum=2

Comment: I have complex logic, but not in all part of app

Comment: Well for the complex logic parts i would check Vaughn Vernon's score card.

Answer (score 0):

DDD is not a good fit for CRUD operations, however, in my experience a lot of those simple CRUD application tend to grow to something a lot more complex then initially thought. Be careful about considering something waste, before you know it, you wished you had used DDD.

What you could do for now is to use DDD for the more complex parts and leave the CRUD operation as simple as possible, then when it becomes more complex, you at least have a framework in place to use a DDD approach.